# Контейнер с социальными сетями растягивается

Tags: css, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 mt-3 px-0 pl-xl-5 mt-md-0 header--contacts" style="background: #000;">
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-between header--contacts---socials" style="background: tan;">
        <span style="background: gold;">
           <a href="https://vk.com/digital_agency_73" target="blank" class="mr-2 header--contacts---social1 header--contacts---social"></a>
           <a href="" target="blank" class="header--contacts---social2 header--contacts---social"></a>
       </span>
       <span class="align-self-center header--contacts---links">
           <a href="" class="pr-1 header--contacts---link">Контакты</a>
           <a href="" class="header--contacts---link">Обратная связь</a> 
       </span>      
   </span>
</div>
```

Почему при добавлении обертки из тега `<span>` к ссылкам-иконкам у него появляется лишнее пространство внизу? Паддинги не стоят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также проблема может быть решена добавлением свойства `vertical-align: middle;` к иконкам соц.сетей внутри инлайн элемента. Это пространство резервируется под хвосты букв. 
Прочитал здесь [лишнее место под img](http://learn.javascript.ru/space-under-img)

Comment: Попробуйте исследовать элемент через браузер, загляните в стили и продебажьте. Попробуйте убрать связанные `CSS` правила и проанализируйте поведение. Может быть padding-bottom стоит? Или же иконки меньше чем контейнер.

Comment: Ты убрал margin и padding у этих элементов?

Comment: Да, все убрано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например вот так: добавьте оборачивающему спану `.d-flex`, а ссылкам `.d-flex.align-items-center`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 mt-3 px-0 pl-xl-5 mt-md-0 header--contacts" style="background: #000;">
  <span class="d-flex justify-content-between header--contacts---socials" style="background: tan;">
        <span class="d-flex" style="background: gold;">
           <a href="https://vk.com/digital_agency_73" target="blank" class="d-flex align-items-center mr-2 header--contacts---social1 header--contacts---social">social</a>
           <a href="" target="blank" class="d-flex align-items-center header--contacts---social2 header--contacts---social">social</a>
       </span>
  <span class="align-self-center header--contacts---links">
           <a href="" class="pr-1 header--contacts---link">Конт<br>акты</a>
           <a href="" class="header--contacts---link">Обратная связь</a> 
       </span>
  </span>
</div>
```